# Site title is shown in small font size in IE

Tags: css, mybb

I need CSS help.

In [this](http://forum.indiaconsumercomplaints.org/index.php) site header the site name "India Consumer Complaints Forum" is show in small font in IE 9 while it works fine in other browsers. I've tried [this suggestion](http://community.mybb.com/thread-138079.html) from a Mybb expert too but it does not work. I've tried other options like using 2.5em for font-size or moving font-size into #logotext id too but IE seems to be immune to it.

How can I show it in bigger font?

[image]

Comment: first check your page zoom

Comment: Check your IE version.

Comment: set **body** to **font-size: 100%;** and then use ems. I had the same problem and this worked for me

Comment: I've checked and IE version is 9.0.8112.16421 64 bit. It still displays the same.

Comment: Not reproduceable. This could be an error or odd setting in your copy of IE.

Comment: I too think so. In IE 9 of laptop it shows ok. But not in PC. I've cleared the the Browsing History a couple of times( with Preserve Favorites, Temporary Internet files, Cookies,History SELECTED). Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your site link shows big in every browser, checked back to IE7. No issues found. You might have fixed it.

Comment: I haven't. My IE version is IE version is 9.0.8112.16421 64 bit.